# Remove punctuation from beginning and end of words in a string

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have a string and I want to remove any `- ,( ,) ,& ,$ ,# ,! ,[ ,] ,{ ,} ," ,'` from the beginning or end of the word. If it is between the words just ignore those.

Here is an example:

```
var $string = "Hello I am a string, and I am called Jack-Tack!. My -mom is Darlean.";
```

I want the above text to be like this after a regex:

```
console.log("Hello I am a string and I am called Jack-Tack My mom is Darlean");
```

Comment: With 'between the words' do you mean inside a word?

Comment: your example removes the puntuation insides the string also, edit your title to "Remove punctuation from string with js" or edit the example. And jQuery is for DOM manipulation, not for data manipulation

Comment: It isn't really clear what "Hello!^ there" and "Hello^! there" should be converted into. My solution will convert the former into "Hello^ there" and leave the latter untouched where as Joseph Silber's solution will do the opposite (convert the latter into "Hello^ there" while leaving the former untouched). It all depends on what "a word" is for you.

Answer (score 9):

You can use the fact that `\b` in regular expressions always matches at a word boundary whereas `\B` matches only where there isn't a word boundary. What you want is removing this set of characters only when there is a word boundary on one side of it but not on the other. This regular expression should do:

```
var str = "Hello I'm a string, and I am called Jack-Tack!. My -mom is Darlean.";
str = str.replace(/\b[-.,()&$#!\[\]{}"']+\B|\B[-.,()&$#!\[\]{}"']+\b/g, "");
console.log(str); // Hello I'm a string and I am called Jack-Tack My mom is Darlean
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's one I just created. It could probably be simplified, but it works.

```
"Hello I am a string, and I am called Jack-Tack!. My -mom is Darlean."
.replace(/(?:[\(\)\-&$#!\[\]{}\"\',\.]+(?:\s|$)|(?:^|\s)[\(\)\-&$#!\[\]{}\"\',\.]+)/g, ' ')
.trim();
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace this regex with an empty string.

```
/(?<=\s)[^A-Z]+?(?=\w)|(?<=\w)[^a-z]*?(?=\s|$)/gi

//Explanation:
/
(?<=\s)[^A-Z]+?(?=\w)    //Find any non-letters preceded by a space and followed by a word
|                        //OR
(?<=\w)[^a-z]*?(?=\s|$)  //Any non-letters preceded by a work and followed by a space.
/gxi
```